# HTMLAgilitypack testing parent node attribute value

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Here is what the context : I use HTMLAgilityPack to select P node like this :

```
var paragraphe = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//p[not(descendant::p)]");
```

Then using a for loop, I you like to test for each time, if the parent of this DOM element is a DIV and contains a specific attribute such as : `div[@edth_correction='N']`

But I have no idea how to get the parent node, I have already written all the code for the work I have to do.

I know that I can do something like this : `paragraphe[i].ParentNode.Attributes.Equals()` but I have no idea what to write in this Equals and if it is what I have to use for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
var paragraphe = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//p[not(descendant::p)]");

for (int i = 0; i < paragraphe.Count; i++)
{
    var parent = paragraphe[i].ParentNode;

    if (parent.Name == "div" &&
        parent.ChildAttributes("edth_correction").Any(a => a.Value == "N"))
    {
        // do work
    }
}
```

Another way: check the parent node and attribute with XPath.

```
var paras = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
    "//p[not(descendant::p) and name(..)='div' and ../@edth_correction='N']");

foreach (var p in paras)
{
    // do work
}
```

---

To test node ancestors try this

```
var paragraphe = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//p[not(descendant::p)]");

for (int i = 0; i < paragraphe.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (var ancestor in paragraphe[i].Ancestors("div"))
    {
        if (ancestor.ChildAttributes("edth_correction").Any(a => a.Value == "N"))
        {
            // do work
        }
    }
}
```

Or with XPath

```
var paras = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
    "//p[not(descendant::p) and ancestor::div/@edth_correction='N']");

foreach (var p in paras)
{
    // do work
}
```

I'm not sure about the second approach. Since I don't know your data source.

Also you can try XPath

```
"//p[not(descendant::p) and ancestor::*[name(.)='div' and ./@edth_correction='N']]"
```

Comment: I used your first answer and it totaly work like I needed to for the selection, thanks a lot mate.

Comment: Just one quick update, if i needed to check not the direct parent but far from it (like '<div edth_correction="N"><div><p>no correction as on of his parent in the DOM got the attribute at value= N</p></div><div>'). Should I proceed by repeating this test or is there a way with HTMLAgilityPack ?

Comment: Like should I use 'paragraphe[i].ParentNode.Ancestor' ? then proceed to iterate on the returned list to see if there is a match with the attribute value ?

Comment: It selected correctly everything I need, but made me have another issue. I'll try solving it by myself as it does not concerne this specific part. Thanks a lot mate.